# Хочу использовать `slug = name` в качестве идентификатора модели в URI

Tags: php, ооп, framework, laravel

Хочу использовать такой URL: `mydomen.ru/user/username`

Mодель User:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function getRouteKey()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

}

Роут выглядит так:

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'UserController@show');
```

Это контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class UserController extends Controller
{      
    /** ... */

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {            
        return view('user/show',
            ['user'=>$user->toJson()]
        );
    }

    /** ... */
}
```

Это в RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    $router->model('user', 'App\User');

    parent::boot($router);
}
```

Что я упустил? Почему по-прежнему URL привязан к `user.id` а не к `user.name`, как я хочу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `RouteServiceProvider` вы используете код:

```
$router->model('user', 'App\User');
```

Давайте посмотрим, что здесь происходит.

Файл `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php`

```
/**
 * Register a model binder for a wildcard.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  string  $class
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function model($key, $class, Closure $callback = null)
{
   $this->bind($key, function ($value) use ($class, $callback) {
       if (is_null($value)) {
            return;
       }

        // For model binders, we will attempt to retrieve the models using the first
        // method on the model instance. If we cannot retrieve the models we'll
        // throw a not found exception otherwise we will return the instance.
        $instance = $this->container->make($class);

        if ($model = $instance->where($instance->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first()) {
            return $model;
        }

        // If a callback was supplied to the method we will call that to determine
        // what we should do when the model is not found. This just gives these
       // developer a little greater flexibility to decide what will happen.
       if ($callback instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func($callback, $value);
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    });
}
```

Обратите внимание на код

```
if ($model = $instance->where($instance->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first()) {
    return $model;
}
```

Здесь используется метод модели `getRouteKeyName()`.

**Обращаю ваше внимание на то, что вы переопределяете другой метод**: `getRouteKey()`.
Это основная ваша ошибка.

Рассмотрим код далее. Проследим всю цепочку начиная с `getRouteKeyName()`

Файл `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php`

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return $this->getKeyName();
}
```

```
/**
 * Get the primary key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKeyName()
{
    return $this->primaryKey;
}
```

```
/**
 * The primary key for the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

Итак, таким образом выходит, что по умолчанию метод `getRouteKeyName()` класса `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` возвращает имя первичного ключа, которое равно `id`.

Следовательно, вам нужно переопределить этот метод таким образом, чтобы тот возвращал **имя нужного вам столбца** в таблице. И это должна быть **строка**.

Таким образом, из вашей модели вам нужно **удалить** свой метод:

```
public function getRouteKey()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

И **добавить** следующий:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

---

Рекомендую вам к просмотру видео **[Route Model Binding](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/18)** из серии **[Laravel 5 Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals)**

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Наверняка, он должен помочь. Пока все перестало работать - но это хороший знак - значит что-то изменилось :)

Comment: Да, понял свою ошибку. Строка должна была быть названием поля. Спасибо еще раз ;) Вот так заработало: 
`public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'name';
    }`

Comment: Да это я вас в заблуждение ввел, по запарке указав slug вместо name. Прошу меня извинить

Answer (score 0):

Вполне достаточно:

```
Route::get('user/{user:name}', 'UserController@show');
```

[Документация](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-key).